# How do I properly make click event on fetched "buttons"?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I fetch all users from database via this code

```
fetch("/api/v1/users", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
})
.then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
})
.then(function(json) {
    json.data.forEach((elem) => {
        Object.values(elem).forEach((item) => {
            if(item != "" && typeof item == "string") {
                document.querySelector('.users__list').appendChild(users.createElement('div', 'users__user-field', '', `<p>${item}</p>`))
            }
        })
    })
})
```

After they fetched, I generate an element and add that element to the list. That works fine, but!

I have this part of code

```
const selectableUsers = {
    users: document.querySelectorAll('.users__user-field'),
    click(elem) {
        this.reset()
        elem.classList.toggle('selected')
    },
    reset() {
        this.users.forEach((elem) => {
            elem.classList.remove('selected')
        })
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.users__user-field').forEach((elem) => {elem.addEventListener('click', () => {selectableUsers.click(elem)})})
}
```

In my logic, after elements generated, and window loaded, all items with class `users__user-field` must have a click event to toggle `selected` class. But that's doesn't work. I have no idea why. Can you help me?

Comment: Your assumption, that the elements _were_ generated, before the load event fires, is probably wrong. The keyword you should go read up on, is _event delegation_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you suppose that users are fetched and added as DOM elements loading the window, which is wrong. Once window loaded, you try to add select event to an empty list of DOM elements, you should set the select behavior after fetching users list like that :

```js
fetch("/api/v1/users", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
})
.then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
})
.then(function(json) {
    json.data.forEach((elem) => {
        Object.values(elem).forEach((item) => {
            if(item != "" && typeof item == "string") {
                document.querySelector('.users__list').appendChild(users.createElement('div', 'users__user-field', '', `<p>${item}</p>`))
// -------------->
                document.querySelectorAll('.users__user-field').forEach((elem) => {elem.addEventListener('click', () => {selectableUsers.click(elem)})})            
// -------------->
             }
        })
    })
})
```